# Why does this smartphone picture show a "disconnected" body?

Tags: hdr, smartphone

This picture was taken at the beach around 11 am in the morning , using Samsung J4 plus with its natural camera 
[image]

Comment: Was the camera set for "panorama" mode?

Comment: Removed autofocus tag, since the problem is not about the picture being out of focus.

Answer (score 5):

Simple. Your camera just took 2 pictures.

It means that you have some settings configured on your camera that you need to know what are they.

Two options come to my mind.

1. As Michael C noted on the comment, you have some kind of "Panorama mode".
2. You have some sort of HDRI mode.

There are several techniques that involve taking several pictures to be composed into one image. The two I mentioned doing that.

But the mode that is more likely to be is the "panorama" because the other one I mentioned involves different exposures, which is not the case.

---

It means that the camera was expecting you to move the camera but the one that moved was the subject, and the camera just simply composed two images.